# Display html button in php

Tags: php

I want to display my button in php. The link works, but the button is not displayed. How do I solve this?

```
 if ($_SESSION['type'] == $r['type']) {

    $link = 'random.php';
    printf(' <a href="' .$link. '">
                <button  class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  style="background-image:url("./image.jpg"); height:52px; width:152px;">                    
                </button>
                </a> ');
                }
```

Comment: What do you really want to use? `a` or `button`?

Comment: Both. The `a` works fine, the link is working. But the `button` is not displayed - it's an little empty box instead.

Comment: Why not just use `a` then style it like its a `button`?

Comment: This is probably a quote issue in your html - `style="background-image:url("./image.jpg"); height:52px; width:152px;"`. You have `"` both wrapping the `style` attributes, and in your `url()`. Try changing it to `style="background-image:url(\'./image.jpg\'); height:52px; width:152px;"` (note, need to escape the single quotes `\'`)

Comment: have you inspected the output html code to ensure that the url is pointing to a valid file?

Comment: Yea its working! If you want just copy my answer below and I'll give you the answer check! Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/689579/sean):

```
if ($_SESSION['type'] == $r['type']) {

    $link = 'random.php';
    printf(' <a href="' .$link. '">
                <button  class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  style="background-image:url(\'./images.jpg\'); height:52px; width:152px;">                 
                </button>
                </a> ');
                }
```